# Magento throws error when i try to import Database saying the server recieved a bad request

Tags: php, magento

I am new to this Magento. I have created a magento site in my test server where everything works just fine. Now i am trying to migrate the site to the live server. I backup up all my files and the database. I uploaded the files to the live server cpanel file manager, created a new database, assigned user previllages and imported the database.And now when the database is  getting imported after a bit of long time the server throws this error [Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4tpp.png) 
And when i refresh the phpmyadmin page i see all the tables got imported in that database. But when i open the site url in the browser it shows 500 Internal Server Error..
Pls help how can i overcome these issues and migrate my site to live domain...

Answer (score 0):

For migrating You have to change **app/etc/local.xml** for new updated database detail.

after that you have to change **secure and unsecure** url in **core_config_data**. In this you have to udpate live url site.

for this search **path** like **secure** keyword in above table. you find old url. You have to replace with new one.

after that clean cache.

It may be work for you.